# Filter country using a JOIN in BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

In a scheduled query in BQ, I am trying to filter countries using an external Google Sheet (already made a table). The query already has a join from two other tables. I would like to enter a SELECT clause in the WHERE statement.

```
SELECT
    DATE(e_time) AS date,
    DATE(i_time) AS i_date,
    DATE_DIFF(DATE(e_time),DATE(i_time),day) AS days_since_install,
    country_code AS country,
  FROM
    `data.sessions`
  WHERE
    DATE(e_time)= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 day)
    AND country_code = (
    SELECT
      country_code as country
    FROM
      `data.sessions` a
   INNER JOIN
      `data.country_filter` b
    ON
      string_field_0 = a.country_code)
```

I keep getting errors. Any tips as to where I am going wrong? Expected output would be table 1 with the filtered countries from table b. Thank you in advance.

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: Hi Zaynul. I edited the post. Thanks!

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table table and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: Hello, I updated the post with the information! Thank you :)

Comment: What errors are you getting?  When I connect Google Sheets, the most common error I have are permissions errors, which you need to solve locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your query you have to use in

```
  SELECT
        DATE(e_time) AS date,
        DATE(i_time) AS i_date,
        DATE_DIFF(DATE(e_time),DATE(i_time),day) AS days_since_install,
        country_code AS country,
      FROM
        `data.sessions`
      WHERE
        DATE(e_time)= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 day)
        AND country_code in(
        SELECT
          country_code as country
        FROM
          `data.sessions` a
       INNER JOIN
          `data.country_filter` b
        ON
          string_field_0 = a.country_code)
```

Comment: Actually, with the IN, I do not have to use JOIN. Thanks for your help.